# Troubleshoot formulas in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Troubleshooting formulas can be difficult, and already to find a direction to start may not be easy.

- What can you do when your formula gives an error message?
- What if the formula has an unexpected result?

Although all formulas are different, are there common steps to solve those issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Evaluate formula

When your formula doesn't work as expected, your first step could be to evaluate it (Formulas tab - formula auditing group - evaluate formula)

[image]

Here you can follow calculations step by step by pressing "Evaluate" button.

[Official help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7)

### Reduce complexity / range

If evaluating your formula doesn't solve the issue, mainly because the formula is too complex, refers to a huge number of data and you can't easily overview it, then try to reduce formula / data

- if you have a long formula, try to split it to smaller ones, placing them in separate cells to see which part fails.

  - if all the small parts work correctly, then have the complete formula referring to the sub results
- if your formula refers to a big range, try to limit the cells referred to, concentrating tricky parts in that referred range. This way evaluating the formula will give you better overview.

### Array formulas

[Array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7) can be great, however they can go wrong after edit.
If you see `{  }` around a formula in Excel, then it's an array formula, after editing it, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to keep it as an array formula.

### Asking for help

If you still can't solve it, then maybe it's a good idea to ask for help.

If you decide to ask here, please make sure your question includes:

- the formula your have (the shortest one which produces the error)
- some sample data to be able to test your formula (you can convert your spreadsheet data to markdown e.g. [here](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)
- current and desired results

---

You can also find helpful tips for building formulas in this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/553978/427317).

Comment: .............nice answer..............

Answer (score 1):

press

```
ctrl + `
```

to see all the formulaes available in the sheet,select a part of the formula and press

```
F9
```

to see the output of that part.works for me every time.