# Excel Indirect ref error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a 2 columns with dates (dd/mm/yyyy), I gave both a named range "completed_date" and "survey_date". I made a drop down list in cell "E40" containing "Survey" and "Completed".

I now try to do a countifs:

```
=COUNTIFS(User_for_Survey;$H$5;NPS;E$10;INDIRECT(E40&"_Date");$D44)
```

but I'm getting a ref error.

Though, when I do <kbd>F9</kbd> on the content in the indirect function, I get the named range "Survey_date" or "completed_date".

When I don't use the indirect function, and go direct with the named range, the formula works fine.

Can it have something to do with the date format? When I use different criteria range like week number, and a number as criteria, it works fine.

All my data have the exact same number of rows. I know it's an indirect problem, because when I evaluate my formula, it shows me where the ref error is.

On row 42 I have replaced the indirect function with the named range it should direct too, and it works fine (answer should be 0).

```
=COUNTIFS(User_for_Survey;$H$5;NPS;E$10;Created_date;$D42)
```

Formula:

[image]

Named Range:

[image]

Comment: please have a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1189830/troubleshoot-formulas-in-excel) and update your question.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with Indirect? what do you have in NPS? Does all the references have the same number of rows?

Comment: If you insert a screenshot of your Data it will be helpful

Comment: Sorry Guys, looks like I was being an idiot, problem was an extra space in the data validation list.