# I don't know why this formula is wrong?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Hello I am using this formula

`=IF(Jan>[@[Date From]],[@[Monthly Amortization]],0,if(Jan<[@[Date Until]],[@[Monthly Amortization]],0,if(Jan=[@[Date Until]],[@[Monthly Amortization]],0,if(Jan>[@[Date Until]],0,0))))`

It returns the you've entered too many arguments for this function.
Can someone help with this I would appreciate it.

Comment: What have you tried to fix it? Please follow tips [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1189830/troubleshoot-formulas-in-excel) and edit your question with more details based on it.

Comment: `IF()` can only have 3 criteria, you have 4 in each.  Remove the `,0` from each. and `Jan` is not a native function so it will return #NAME.  You will need to put a date in its place.

Answer (score 3):

You are writing more than Value if True and Value if False in your Nested If
Usually you write"

```
=If(Logical Test, Value if True, Value if False)  
=If(Logical Test, Value if True, IF(Logical Test, Value if True, Value if False))
```

Your corrected formula:

```
=IF(Jan>[@[Date From]],[@[Monthly Amortization]],if(Jan<[@[Date Until]],[@[Monthly Amortization]],if(Jan=[@[Date Until]],[@[Monthly Amortization]],if(Jan>[@[Date Until]],0,0))))
```

But the last if should change, you have Value if True 0 and Value if False 0